# Possible to make Touch Tone Phone Ring with no phone line?

Tags: telephone

I am making an "Activity Board" for my toddler. I'm wanting to make an old touch tone phone ring when he pushes a button or picks up the phone. I am hoping someone can help me or point me in the right direction of making the phone ring. To clarify, it is NOT hooked up to a phone line.

Comment: Check what the specs say the signal should look like and implement a replica

Comment: Phone ringing signal (90 volts or so) and toddler plaything are probably not a good mix, honestly.

Comment: @Ecnerwal: 30Vish should be sufficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A telephone ringer is driven by a high AC voltage oscillating around 30 times per second (70V RMS, 30 Hz). This can vary, up or down, slower or faster. It's not particularly picky.

Below is a simple ***Ring Generator*** circuit, using a transformer wired "backwards", driven by a dual 555 timer (556 IC). It expects 12V 400mA, but again, can use more or less. I suspect You could even power this from a few (6?) AA batteries in series if you didn't want to use a wall wart.

[image]

> [This ring generator](http://www.bowdenshobbycircuits.info/page11.htm#ring1.gif) will ring a telephone once every 10 seconds. The interval between rings can be lengthened or shortened by varying the value of the 1 Meg resistor. The 70 volt/ 30 Hz ring voltage is produced from the 120 volt side of a small 12.6 VAC power transformer (Radio Shack 273-1365). Both capacitors connected across the transformer windings are non-polarized / 100 volts. Circuit draws about 300mA from the 12 volt DC power supply during the ringing interval.

A relay or switch at the +12V node should be used to turn the circuit on.

See [Wiring up old phone ringer to arduino](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5531/wiring-up-old-phone-ringer-to-arduino) or http://www.bowdenshobbycircuits.info/page11.htm#ring2.gif or  https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/50 for some more ideas.